# Meteor SyntaxError after bundling

Tags: meteor

My meteor application works locally. When I bundle it (using `meteor bundle myapp.tgz`), upload it on my server and launch it, I have the following error upon opening the page on Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

On Firefox console:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]   

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In order to try to find the origin of the error, I used an old bundle that was working. I can see the problem is that the files in static_cachable are not found.

> Meteor is still trying to use the files from the old bundle.

If I rename the new bundled files in static_cachable to the old name then **It works**.

I checked in all files contained by the root of the bundle folder and references are correct (they are pointing to the new names).

**It there some cache somewhere that keep the reference to the old static_caches files ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the error, one has to restart Meteor after deployement :

1. rm -rf bundle
2. tar -zxf myapp.tar.gz
3. cd bundle/server/node_modules/
4. rm -r fibers
5. npm install fibers@1.0.0
6. export PORT=32632
7. export MONGO_URL=mongodb://meteor:******@localhost:18700/moviegrid
8. export ROOT_URL='mydomain.com'
9. nohup node bundle/main.js &

Answer (score 0):

Look at the javascript console when you load your app locally and check if there is no error. If there is some, correct them before bundling/deploy.

Comment: As I mentionned in the question, the application works well locally.

Comment: i also had the same king of problem. My app worked locally but not on server. I just missed one js warning in the console, but locally it didn't broke anything. That's why i told you to check that.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your problem but according to http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying:

> For now, bundles will only run on the platform that the bundle was created on. To run on a different platform, you'll need to rebuild the native packages included in the bundle. To do that, make sure you have npm available, and run the following:
>
> $ cd bundle/server/node_modules
>
> $ rm -r fibers
>
> $ npm install fibers@1.0.0

Consider installing meteor on your server, cloning your app directory and using `meteor run` inside the directory to see if the app runs in development on the server.

If it successfully launches in development then bundle it on the server and use those files.  Or just run with `meteor --production`

Comment: What is difficult for me to understand is that this error came when I installed the new version of meteor (Release 0.6.4)

Comment: I found out that Meteor does not find the two files located in the static_cachable folder on my bundler folder. In fact, I have an old version of the bundle that worked. If I copy/paste the two file in my old static_cachable and paste it in the new static_cachable then the application worked again. If I delete those two files I then get my error again.

Comment: I see your answer below and wondered if you might want to rephrase your question.  The phrase 'and launch it' made me think you were starting the app on the server but I guess you meant on the client. No harm in listing the actual commands you were using.